# SmartyPHP Multiple Foreach

Tags: php, html, mysql, smarty

```
<select name="country[]" multiple="multiple" id="type" class="medium" style="width:20%;height:300px;">
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option>---------------------------------</option>

   {foreach from=$country key=id item=n}
     {foreach from=$cntry key=i item=name}

      <option value="{$n}" {if $name == $n}SELECTED{/if}>{$n}</option>
     {/foreach}
   {/foreach}
 </select>
```

For some reason, it's repeating every country I have in an array list 4 times, and it isn't selecting the ones from `$cntry` that match the ones in `$country`.

`$cntry` (selected countries from rows in the DB), while `$country` is just an array list of all the countries.

Comment: can you print like {$name} - {$n} and see what exactly value you are getting ?

Comment: $name = United States, Canada, Australia, Albania. Exploded from an array.
$n = list of all the countries from an array.

Comment: can you paste your array structure of $country and $cntry  ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xtsWA05K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
   {foreach from=$country key=id item=n}
     {assign var=sel value=''}
     {foreach from=$cntry key=i item=name}
        {if $name == $n}{assign var=sel value='selected'}{/if}
     {/foreach}
      <option value="{$n}" {$sel}>{$n}</option>
   {/foreach}
```

Comment: No errors, nothing is selected, but the repeating of items is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You've nested your loops. They should probably be done serially:

```
{foreach from=$country key=id item=n}
   <option blah blah blah>
{/foreach}
{foreach from=$cntry key=i item=name}
   <option blah blah blah >
{/foreach}
```

Comment: They need to work together and not separately. For example 

$cntry = United States, Canada, Australia, Albania. I have exploded those into an array, so that when I add the forreach into $country, it will select based on $cntry.

Comment: From what I can understand, you want the selected dates to appear _above_ the rest of the list, therefore Marc's answer is just what you need.